# Why does BitmapSource.Create throw an ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, bitmapsource, stride

I'm trying to get an bitmap created from raw data to show in WPF, by using an Image and a BitmapSource:

```
Int32[] data = new Int32[RenderHeight * RenderWidth];

for (Int32 i = 0; i < RenderHeight; i++)
{
    for (Int32 j = 0; j < RenderWidth; j++)
    {
        Int32 index = j + (i * RenderHeight);

        if (i + j % 2 == 0)
            data[index] = 0xFF0000;
        else
            data[index] = 0x00FF00;
    }
}

BitmapSource source = BitmapSource.Create(RenderWidth, RenderHeight, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, data, 0);

RenderImage.Source = source;
```

However the call to BitmapSource.Create throws an ArgumentException, saying "Value does not fall within the expected range". Is this not the way to do this? Am I not making that call properly?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your stride is incorrect. Stride is the number of bytes allocated for one scanline of the 
bitmap. Thus, use the following:

```
int stride = ((RenderWidth * 32 + 31) & ~31) / 8;
```

and replace the last parameter (currently `0`) with `stride` as defined above.

Here is an explanation for the mysterious stride formula:

Fact: Scanlines must be aligned on 32-bit boundaries ([reference](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm)).

The naive formula for the number of bytes per scanline would be:

```
(width * bpp) / 8
```

But this might not give us a bitmap aligned on a 32-bit boundary and (width * bpp) might not even have been divisible by 8.

So, what we do is we force our bitmap to have at least 32 bits in a row (we assume that `width > 0`):

```
width * bpp + 31
```

and then we say that we don't care about the low-order bits (bits 0--4) because we are trying to align on 32-bit boundaries:

```
(width * bpp + 31) & ~31
```

and then divide by 8 to get back to bytes:

```
((width * bpp + 31) & ~31) / 8
```

The padding can be computed by

```
int padding = stride - (((width * bpp) + 7) / 8)
```

The naive formula would be

```
stride - ((width * bpp) / 8)
```

But `width * bpp` might not align on a byte boundary and when it doesn't this formula would over count the padding by a byte. (Think of a 1 pixel wide bitmap using 1 bpp. The stride is 4 and the naive formula would say that the padding is 4 but in reality it is 3.) So we add a little bit to cover the case that `width * bpp` is not a byte boundary and then we get the correct formula given above.

Comment: Thank you, but how on earth did you come up with that expression? Why isn't it simply RenderWidth * 4? Isn't that the number of bytes for one line?

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided details. In your case you have `bpp = 32` so yes the formula reduces to `RenderWidth * 4`. But there are odd cases (cheap LCDs use 18 bpp) and the fact that scanlines have to be aligned on 32-bit boundaries. I provided the general formula and an explanation of how to come up with it above. Hope it's elucidating.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. What does the tilde do on an integer like that?

Comment: @Mike Pateras: It is the bitwise not operator. That means that it flips the bits in the binary representation of the integer (so `0` becomes `1` and `1` becomes `0`). I said that we want to ignore the lowest five bits of `width * bpp + 31` (and implicitly keep the rest). An easy way to do that is to make a number that has `0` in those five bits and a `1` in the rest of the bits; this is called a bitmask. If we take the logical and  `width * bpp + 31` with this bitmask (`~31`) we have masked away the five low-order bits that we don't care about. Let me know if that isn't clear.

Comment: I spent all day messing with this and your post helped me fix my code in 30 seconds. Thank you VERY much!!! and if anyone needs to know, `((width * 24 + 23) & ~23) / 8;` works with `PixelFormats.Rgb24;`.

Comment: @Jason could you please tell me how to calculate stride for PixelFormats.Rgb24  i tried these three methods, but none seems to working good
    //int stride = 4 * ((width * bytesPerPixel + 3) / 4);//one way 
    //int stride = ((width * 32 + 31) & ~31) / 8;// another way
    //int stride = ((width * 24 + 23) & ~23) / 8;// yet another way

Comment: @Raj Minimum stride to contain data of a certain bpp is `((bpp * width) + 7) / 8;`, and with that as `GetMinStride` function, the full 4-byte-aligned stride would be `((GetMinStride(width, bpp) + 3) / 4) * 4;`