# conversion of image to byte array

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone please tell me how an image(.jpg,.gif,.bmp) is converted into a byte array ?

Comment: Where do you have your image? In a file or in an Image object or some Stream?

Comment: image is uploaded into a picturebox using an OpenFileDialog

Comment: Why do you need your image as a byte array? For storage? or are you trying to manipulate the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've assumed what you want is the pixel values. Assuming `bitmap` is a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource`:

```
int stride = bitmap.PixelWidth * ((bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
byte[] bmpPixels = new byte[bitmap.PixelHeight * stride];
bitmap.CopyPixels(bmpPixels, stride, 0);
```

Note that the 'stride' is the number of bytes required for each row of pixel ddata. Some more explanation available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004602/any-can-explain-the-function-of-stride-in-bitmapdata).

Comment: Why the downvote? Surely the question can be interpreted as 'I want the image pixel values as a byte array' or 'I want the image file as a byte array'?

Comment: Your answer didn't originally have the third line, and your first line threw me until I had some coffee. Edit it and I'll undo my down-vote.

Comment: Fair point, thanks for explaining :)  I've added a brief note on what the stride is.

Comment: Actually, are you sure your stride calculation is right? The stride needs to be 32-bit aligned, but I think your code just makes it 8-bit aligned.

Comment: It was quite a while ago I wrote the code, and I remember spending quite some time on figuring it out. I definately works :)  Some more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185944/why-must-stride-in-the-system-drawing-bitmap-constructor-be-a-multiple-of-4 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983781/why-does-bitmapsource-create-throw-an-argumentexception/1983886#1983886. My head hurts :)

Comment: Your stride calculation would work for any 32-bit-per-pixel format, since it's already 32-bit aligned. Fortunately, the default Bitmap in .Net is ARGB8888.

Comment: Ah yes, it's coming back to me now!

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to convert an image to bytes is to use the ImageConverter class under the System.Drawing namespace

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If your image is already in the form of a `System.Drawing.Image`, then you can do something like this:

```
public byte[] convertImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif); 
             // or whatever output format you like
         return ms.ToArray(); 
     }
}
```

You would use this function with the image in your picture box control like this:

```
byte[] imageBytes = convertImageToByteArray(pictureBox1.Image);
```

Comment: @riya7887: please use my edited version above, since it disposes the stream properly.

Answer (score 0):

to get the bytes from any file try:

```
byte[] bytes =  File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off of MusiGenesis; helped me a lot but I had many image types.  This will save any image type that it can read.

```
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat ImageFormat = imageToConvert.RawFormat;
        byte[] Ret;
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                imageToConvert.Save(ms, ImageFormat);
                Ret = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
        return Ret;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) method to get bytes

If you are using [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) class then you can use [FileBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes.aspx) Property to get the Bytes as Byte Array.