# how to insert a picture through insert method?

Tags: c#, sql

I have an insert method that takes all the input and stores them in the database, but I don't know how to represent the picture in the method.

For Example:

```
memberTableAdapter.Insert(textBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, pictureBox1);
```

I cannot even compile the program because there is an error in the method's format. There is some thing should be written instead of pictureBox1 alone because it asks me to write byte[] type, or something like that.

- The datatype for the picture in SQLserver is varbinary(MAX).
- PictureBox is a tool that show the picture.

Could you please help what should I write instead of pictureBox1?

Thanks for you all,

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please edit your post to give more information.

Comment: And what is pictureBox1?

Comment: What is the type of column in database?

Comment: you have to convert `pictureBox1.Image` to `byte[]` array. check out the answers in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050954/conversion-of-image-to-bytearray)

Comment: Thank you all,  th1rdey3 I went to the provided link and i wasn't able to understand it very well. would you please write the code for me. I tried to write convert.ToByte(pictureBox1.image) but it didn't work.